# Windows: redirect stdout and stderror to nothing

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-command-prompt, stdout

I have a command I am running produces a ton of output, I want to silence the output without writing to a file. I have used the following to send all output to a file:

```
command > out.txt 2>&1
```

... but again I don't want any file output:

```
command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I have used `command > /dev/null` on my CentOS box before, but I can't find a similar thing for windows.

Comment: I hope you used `command > /dev/null` on your CentOS.

Comment: @pipitas whatever i did it worked :D

Comment: If you indeed used `command > /bin/null` on CentOS, you have created a common file file named `/bin/null` on your system. You may say *'It worked!'*, if you want. This file now contains the stdout **and** stderr output of your `command`. Usually, in `/bin/` there are only executable files. And usually, only the *root* user is allowed to create files there. So if that file is there, you did run your command as root user... `/bin/null` usually doesn't exist -- and `/dev/null` (which I mentioned) usually is used as the *'black whole'* where unwanted output should disappear in...

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of that. However, I am pretty sure it is just my faulty memory because I was on Windows at the time.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You want `command > nul 2>&1`.

Comment: thanks! that works. I need to wait 12 minutes to accept the answer though (serverfault requirement)!

Comment: This only redirects stdout. You also need `> nul 2>&1` or `2> nul` to kill stderr.

Comment: Yes I know that, but thanks for mentioning it for others that visit this question!

Comment: just to add, I was getting permission denied error while using :
 sudo hostname -f  2> nul
whereas following command worked well : 
 sudo hostname -f  2> /dev/null
For those who run out into permission issue while using nul

Comment: @JedDaniels what is meaning of '> nul' ??

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Visual Studio's cl.exe currently on Windows 10.

Comment: @Ranvir because this question is specific to Windows. You're obviously using a *nix OS, which is drastically different.

Comment: @AminM `nul` is Windows'  special keyword for a null output (i.e. discard output). On *nix-based systems (like Ranvir is referring to) they instead use the special file `/dev/null`. The `>` means "redirect" (and `2>` means redirect buffer 2 -- which is the error output)

Comment: @DoktorJ tnx for answer

Answer (score 4):

You want `command > $null 2>&1`

`nul` only works in command prompt whereas `$null` works in powershell.

Comment: Command Prompt is cmd.exe.  '> null' creates a file called 'null' with whatever you're directing into it from cmd.exe and from PowerShell.